# summarise does not return warning from max when no non-NA values

Tags: r, dplyr, warnings

When `max(x, na.rm = TRUE)` is called with no non-`NA` values, it returns `-Inf`, with a warning. However, in certain cases, the `summarise` function in `dplyr` does not return the warning:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(a = c("a","b"), b = c(NA,NA))
df1 %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise(x = max(b, na.rm = TRUE))
# Three warnings, as expected.

df2 <- data.frame(a = c("a","b"), b = c(1,NA))
df2 %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise(x = max(b, na.rm = TRUE))
# No warning. Unexpected.
```

Interestingly, if I rename the function, I get the warnings as expected:

```
# Pointer to same function.
stat <- max

df1 <- data.frame(a = c("a","b"), b = c(NA,NA))
df1 %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise(x = stat(b, na.rm = TRUE))
# Three warnings, as expected.

df2 <- data.frame(a = c("a","b"), b = c(1,NA))
df2 %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise(x = stat(b, na.rm = TRUE))
# Single warning, as expected.
```

Actually, I think it should be *two* warnings instead of three, because there are only two groups to `summarise`. But I am not sure how the internal warning system works, so perhaps three warnings is as expected.

My question is: Why does `summarise` not output the warning in specific cases, and if that is expected, why would a simple rename of the function change this behaviour?

My `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.5.0.9000 magrittr_1.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] lazyeval_0.2.0.9000 R6_2.2.0            assertthat_0.1
[4] tools_3.3.2         DBI_0.5-1           tibble_1.2
[7] Rcpp_0.12.8
```

Although I am using the "dev" version of `dplyr`, I have also tested it on the version available in CRAN, with the same results.

Comment: Looks like a bug in `group_by` to me as `summarise` gives expected output without it. Also, `mutate` doesn't return a warning neither for your second case.

Comment: Also, In your second case you are getting `NA` instead of `-Inf` which means the problem accrued somewhere before the warning

Comment: Good catch. `df2 %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise(length(na.omit(b)))` does seem to confirm that group `b` is passing a zero-length vector to `max()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `max()`, a hybrid version is available that works much faster for a grouped data frame, because the entire evaluation can be carried out in C++ without R callback for each group. In dplyr 0.5.0, the hybrid version is triggered when all of the following conditions are met:

- The first argument refers to a variable that exists in the data frame
- The second argument is a `logical` constant

See the [hybrid vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/hybrid-evaluation.html) for more detail.

The hybrid version of `max()` differs in certain aspects from the R implementation:

- No warnings are raised for an empty vector, silently returning `-Inf`

  - I think this was always the case; we might as well add a warning here, but I suspect that [other users won't be happy about this](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1455)
- An all-`NA` vector will return `NA` even with `na.rm = TRUE`

  - This is certainly a bug, I [filed an issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2305)

In your example, `c(NA, NA)` is a vector of `logical`, so dplyr falls back to "regular" evaluation with one R callback for each group. If you need the original behavior, simply use a wrapper or an alias; the hybrid evaluator will fall back to regular evaluation:

```
max_ <- max
data_frame(a = NA_real_) %>% summarise(a = max_(a, na.rm = TRUE))
## # A tibble: 1 × 1
##       a
##   <dbl>
## 1  -Inf
## Warning message:
## In max_(a, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: Useful to know. How can the user tell from the R command-line which `max()` gets dispatched by `dplyr`, without looking at C++ source?

Comment: @smci: As of very recently, there are internal functions `verify_hybrid()` and `verify_not_hybrid()` that allow this kind of test, but they are not yet documented and subject to change. See https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/pull/2306.

Answer (score 6):

Below is a partial diagnosis; proves that somehow dplyr is messing up the reference to function name `max()`. Also, dplyr generally uses SE (Standard Evaluation) on its args: `lazyeval::lazydots(..., .follow_symbols=F))`, so maybe that affects the promise, although I can't see how:

A) `group_by()` is not the culprit. `df2 %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise(length(na.omit(b)))`
does prove that group b is passing a vector with one NA element to `max()`

B) **When we reference max by its qualified name `base::max`, we do see the warning:**

```
> df2 %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise(x = base::max(b, na.rm = TRUE))
       a     x
1      a     1
2      b  -Inf
Warning message:
In base::max(NA_real_, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

And I checked that there is no `dplyr:::max()`, so it's not namespace shadowing.

B2) Similarly, `do.call(max, ...)` gives the warning as expected.

```
> df2 %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise(x = do.call(max, list(b, na.rm = TRUE)))
       a     x
1      a     1
2      b  -Inf
Warning message:
In .Primitive("max")(NA_real_, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

C) Also, note dplyr generally uses SE (Standard Evaluation) on its args: `lazyeval::lazydots(..., .follow_symbols=F))`, but I can't see how that would cause this.

C2) I tried to recreate the internal result of the group_by with:

```
grouped_df(as.numeric(NA), list()), na.rm=T)
```

and to recreate the promise with something like:

```
p <- lazyeval::lazy_dots( max, list( grouped_df(as.numeric(NA), list()), na.rm=T )  , .follow_symbols=F)
```

I couldn't manage to formulate that with `.follow_symbols=T`

I know almost nothing about Standard Evaluation, so sleuth on at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html#metaprogramming

Versions used: dplyr 0.5.0 ; lazyeval 0.1.10 ; although lazyeval 0.2.0 is Hadley's latest

Comment: Nice detective work. I suspect that, internally, max is being overridden by a [C++ function](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/80bfdc7b932b910af23d368996a4bd33a4393bcf/inst/include/dplyr/Result/Max.h)

Comment: Personally I suspect `lazyeval::lazydots(..., .follow_symbols=F))`, but I can't see how it would make a difference in this case.